# How to store exponential values using python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to perform a digit divided by larger value(2/5000000) and then store that value in table, but the problem is when i save that value, only 0 is stored , instead of correct value.I tried with float, double precision, but still only 0 is stored, is there any other way .

Thank you

Comment: In Python 2, division gives integer results unless you use `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: @S.Lott: or unless you use float arguments. 2.0/5000000000 works fine.

Comment: @Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski: Totally true.  However, I'm guessing that someone who didn't try that yet is very, very confused about floating-point and needs something that requires less actual thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to operate on floating numbers, and not convert it after the operation. E.g. `2/5000000.`

Also, use the Decimal library, if you are looking for more accurate decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use floating point division. To be explicit, you can cast ints to float:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 5000000
>>> c = a/float(b)
>>> c
4e-07
```

You can cast either a or b to float.